# PHP class giving error of undefined public var that is declared

Tags: php, class, object, logging, variable-declaration

I'm writing a PHP class for a Logger. I've declared two public vars `$file_log` and `$file_log_error`.

```
class Logger
{
    //constants declaration
    const FILE_BASE = '/log/comunio-uk-log-';

    // property declaration
    protected $file_log = '';
    protected $file_log_error = '';

    // Constructor
    function __construct() {
        $date = getdate();
        $file_log_name = self::FILE_BASE.$date["mday"]."-".$date["mon"]."-".$date["year"].".log";
        $file_log_error_name = self::FILE_BASE.$date["mday"]."-".$date["mon"]."-".$date["year"].".log.error";
        $this->file_log = $file_log_name;
        $this->file_log_error = $file_log_error_name;

        if (file_exists($this->file_log )) {
            echo "#OK for 'file_log' var: <br><pre>", print_r($this->file_log, true), "</pre><br><br>";
        } else {
            echo "#OK for 'file_log' var: <br><pre>", print_r($this->file_log, true), "</pre><br><br>";;
        }

        if (file_exists($this->file_log_error)) {
            echo "#ERROR for 'file_log_error' var: <br><pre>", print_r($this->$file_log_error, true), "</pre><br><br>";
        } else {
            echo "#ERROR for 'file_log_error' var: <br><pre>", print_r($this->$file_log_error, true), "</pre><br><br>";
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a new class object, the constructor is called and I receive the following error:

```
#OK for 'file_log': 
/log/comunio-uk-log-13-2-2016.log

#ERROR for 'file_log_error': 

Notice:  Undefined variable: file_log_error in C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\comuniazo-uk\api\bd\logger.php on line 28

Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\comuniazo-uk\api\bd\logger.php on line 28
```

**Why the first protected var `$file_log` is recognized and the second one,  `$file_log_error`, isn't it?**

I've already try declaring the vars as public and private. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file_log_error` is never defined. Replace

```
print_r($this->$file_log_error, true)
```

with

```
print_r($this->file_log_error, true)
```

If you write

```
$varName = 'test';
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->test = 'foo';
$obj->varName = 'bar';
echo $obj->$varName; // echo $obj->test gives 'foo', not 'bar'
```